# Installed Samba on Ubuntu 20.04 when the share is created it has a lock on the ICON how do I remove the lock to copy files to location

Tags: samba

This is a very new install of 20.04 and there are no other software or add-ons that have been installed.  It's green.  I just installed samba and immediately after creating the directory "sambashare", the ICON shows a lock.  When I do a list:

$ ls -ltr /
results show directory is owned by sudo

I've tried a number of commands to try and unlock the "sambashare" folder but nothing has yielded good results.

In my last attempt I issue the following in terminal:
$ sudo chown $USER:$USER discworld -R

The locked ICON is still there.  I've also made changes to smb.conf with no positive results - what can I do to this.

Comment: So, you've created "sambashare", but chown "discworld"? Also, what do you mean "owned by sudo"? How is the share defined, and what changes have you made to smb.conf?

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply.  I totally messed that last part up - when I did ls -ltr / the directory I created "sambashare" is owned by root! (had two thoughts going on).  I've been following a number of threads, here in support forum, for this issue.  My samba.conf is basic, I've added a [sambashare] section with the following    [sambashare]
    comment = Samba on Ubuntu
    path = /home/username/sambashare
    read only = no
    browsable = yes

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this issue.  When I originally created the Sambashare on the system I did so under Sudo SU - therefore "root" became the owner.

Today, I went back and used the "user" that I wanted to be owner and created the share and all works fine.

Sometime shooting yourself in the foot makes the pain enough to find a relevant fix!

Thanks for the help